# How Laravel knows the path of classes

Tags: laravel

How Laravel is aware of where the Router class path is? I'm aware of the concept of Facade. Now for instance Route alias point to the Route facade that return the name of the class "router"... how Laravel knows that Router is in the vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing path?

```
/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'router';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The facade is used to resolve whatever is bound to the IoC container using that name, in this case the `router`.

So if you go to `Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php` there is a method called `registerCoreContainerAliases`, this is where the binding is set.

Comment: @RobertoMarra you can accept the answer if it helped :) Thanks!